# RMS Speed of Gas Molecule for Polyatomic Molecules

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

Halliday in his book and also many people say that RMS speed, $v_{rms}$ is $\sqrt{\frac{3RT}{M}}$. However, he used this formula in showing that kinetic energy, $K$, is $\frac32kT$. but how about polyatomic gases such as $H_2$, $O_2$, etc. The polyatomic gas by its equipartition energy law or what so called has $K$ that is not $\frac32kT$, it should be $\frac52kT$ or maybe $\frac72kT$ and by that way, its RMS speed should be $\sqrt{\frac{5RT}{M}}$, or $\sqrt{\frac{7RT}{M}}$. But in that book, he showed that the speed of $H_2$ follow the "monoatomic gas" RMS speed.
Does the equipartition energy law really exist? 
The data in Halliday[image: RMS speed]

Answer (score 6):

From the equipartition of energy, energy is equally distributed to every independent degree of freedom of the molecule. (i.e $\frac{kT}{2}$ per degree of freedom.)

For a monoatomic gas particle, there are three **translational** degrees of freedom, therefore its KE is $\frac{3kT}{2}$, and $v_{rms}$ can quite easily be shown to be $\sqrt{\frac{3RT}{M}}$.

For a polyatomic gas molecule, there are three translational degrees of freedom. The other degrees of freedom are **vibrational/rotational**.

**Only the translational degrees of freedom contribute to the KE (translational) of the gas.** The other degrees of freedom contribute to their respective energies. (i.e rotational or vibrational.)

This is why $v_{rms}$ is always equal to $\sqrt{\frac{3RT}{M}}$.

**For example:**
 A diatomic gas molecule has total energy $\frac{5kT}{2}$. Only $\frac{3kT}{2}$ corresponds to the translational kinetic energy, whereas $\frac{2kT}{2}$ (sigh) corresponds to the rotational kinetic energy. This gives us $v_{rms}$ as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

The equipartition energy with freedom degree $>$ 3 is showing its vibrational and rotational move, not its translational move. That's why the RMS speed is always $\sqrt\frac{3RT}{M}$